Spring Boot + Keycloak Policy Enforcer: Handling 401 for Missing Token Before 403
I'm using Spring Boot as a resource server with Keycloak for authentication and authorization. My setup includes spring-oauth2-resource-server for handling JWT tokens and keycloak-policy-enforcer for endpoint access control. Here’s the desired behavior:

If a request lacks a token or has an invalid token, it should return a 401 Unauthorized.
If a user has a token but lacks permission, it should return a 403 Forbidden.

However, with my current setup, requests without tokens are hitting the policy enforcer, which responds with a 403 instead of a 401.
Current Configuration
Here’s my Spring Security configuration:
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
    http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults());
    http.anonymous(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
    http.oauth2ResourceServer(t -> t.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
    http.sessionManagement(t -> t.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(httpMatcher -> httpMatcher.requestMatchers(whiteList).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated());
    http.exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions.authenticationEntryPoint(new BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint()).accessDeniedHandler(new BearerTokenAccessDeniedHandler()));
    http.addFilterAfter(createPolicyEnforcerFilter(), BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
}

private ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter createPolicyEnforcerFilter() {
    return new ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter(new ConfigurationResolver() {
        @Override
        public PolicyEnforcerConfig resolve(HttpRequest request) {
            try {
                PolicyEnforcerConfig config = JsonSerialization.readValue(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/policy-enforcer.json"), PolicyEnforcerConfig.class);
                config.setAuthServerUrl(serverUrl);
                config.setRealm(realM);
                config.setResource(clientId);
                config.setCredentials(Map.of("secret", clientSecret));

                return config;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    });
}

What I’ve Tried
I've tried adjusting the filter order but am still seeing 403 responses for requests without tokens. Does anyone have suggestions on how to ensure that requests without tokens return a 401 before reaching the policy enforcer?
Thanks in advance for any insights!

Policy enforcement on the authorization server sucks

It appears your question is mostly related to the spring Security Filter order.  I have created a sample repository that shows how to secure an application using Keycloak and call it which you can check here.
Related to your specific filter question, you can see how to ensure the order is appropriate by checking how I configured it here. The main part is to ensure the filter is added before the AuthorizationFilter.  This is explained in further details in the Spring Security documentation.
In your case you are enforcing policies within the filter. In this case you will need to throw either an AccessDeniedException (for 403's) or an AuthenticationException (for 401's) as specified in the documentation.
Spring Security is vast and hard sometimes to find things but it is all available within the docs if you search long enough or just read it all. But hopefully this explains what you are looking for.

i have tried without policy enforcer and it works as expected but the issue comes when i try to use keycloak policy enforcer , request without token is proceed and the enforcer returns 403, do you have experianced any of that

I'm not familiar with that ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter is that within the Keycloak library directly? It sounds like it is not implemented appropriately. Could you do the same thing without using it and just using Spring Security like the example repo I have shared? I have an example filter here. You can enforce it by checking for the authority in your configuration or with method level security.
